# How to open a specific accordion tab on clicking a menu navigation link in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, accordion

I am building a one pager in WordPress. I have a requirement of opening an specific accordion tab on the same page by clicking on a top menu navigation link.

Say for example, when clicking the "Concrete Services" menu link it should navigate below to the "Concrete Services" accordion tab on the same page and should open it.

Below are my HTML, CSS and JavaScript code snippets for the accordion. Something is blocking the accordion content from getting it displayed and I need help.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
  var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
  // Function to open the specified accordion tab
  function openAccordionTab(tabId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
      if (accItem[i].id === tabId) {
        accItem[i].classList.add('open');
      } else {
        accItem[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    }
  }
  // Function to handle hash change event
  function handleHashChange() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    openAccordionTab(hash);
  }
  // Add click event listeners to accordion headings
  for (var i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
    accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
  }
  // Toggle accordion item
  function toggleItem() {
    var itemClass = this.parentNode.classList;
    if (!itemClass.contains('open')) {
      openAccordionTab(this.parentNode.id);
    } else {
      itemClass.remove('open');
    }
  }
  // Initial setup on page load
  handleHashChange();
  // Listen for hash change events
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
});
```

```css
.accordionItem {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.accordionItemHeading {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #002766;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordionItemHeading::after {
  content: "+";
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0%;
  border-radius: 0%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.open .accordionItemHeading {
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #ffc032;
  color: #002766;
}

.open .accordionItemHeading::after {
  content: "-";
  color: #002766;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0%;
  border-radius: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordionItemContent {
  display: block !important;
}

.accordionItemContent .left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
}

.accordionItemContent .right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 52%;
}

.open .accordionItemContent {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -o-transform-origin: top;
  -ms-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.close .accordionItemContent {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -o-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordionItemContent p {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.accordionItemContent ul.custom-bullets {
  color: #ff1b23;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordionItemContent ul.custom-bullets li {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 18px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000000;
}

.accordionItemContent ul.custom-bullets li:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #002766;
}
```

```html
<div id="asphalt-services" class="accordionItem close">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Asphalt Services</h2>
  <div class="accordionItemContent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <p>For anything from new surface paving to replacement or repair, our team of experts is here to get it done right.</p>
      <div style="height:20px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
      <p>We provide service for commercial as well as residential needs, and our team of contractors is experienced in both concrete and asphalt paving and maintenance.</p>
      <div style="height:20px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
      <p>High Quality Asphalt & Concrete is the crew to call when you need a Denver paving company.</p>
      <ul class="custom-bullets">
        <li>Asphalt Paving</li>
        <li>Asphalt Removal and Replacement</li>
        <li>Asphalt Maintenance</li>
        <li>Asphalt Overlays</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <img src="sample-image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="concrete-services" class="accordionItem close">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Concrete Services</h2>
  <div class="accordionItemContent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <p>JavaScript accordions let you squeeze a lot of content into a small space in a Web page.</p>
      <p>This simple accordion degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support JavaScript or CSS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <img src="sample-image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="commercial-services" class="accordionItem close">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Commercial Services</h2>
  <div class="accordionItemContent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <p>JavaScript accordions let you squeeze a lot of content into a small space in a Web page.</p>
      <p>This simple accordion degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support JavaScript or CSS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <img src="sample-image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="residential-services" class="accordionItem close">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Residential Services</h2>
  <div class="accordionItemContent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <p>JavaScript accordions let you squeeze a lot of content into a small space in a Web page.</p>
      <p>This simple accordion degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support JavaScript or CSS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <img src="sample-image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="repair-and-maintenance" class="accordionItem close">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Repair &amp; Maintenance</h2>
  <div class="accordionItemContent">
    <div class="left-column">
      <p>JavaScript accordions let you squeeze a lot of content into a small space in a Web page.</p>
      <p>This simple accordion degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support JavaScript or CSS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <img src="sample-image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a lot that I would change for simplicity sake. However, the actual problem that you are having is you never remove the `close` class when you add the `open` class.

Comment: @imvain2 - I have tried that as well, but it's still not working. Any idea why?